# Calling another class's static method from inner static class

Tags: java, static-methods, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to add a call into a private static inner class which calls another class's static method.

So for example:

```
 public class A {
    public static boolean isNumber(){...};
 }

 public class B {
    private static class C {
        static boolean isNumber() {
             return A.isNumber();
          }
      }
  }
```

I'm not all too familiar with static inner classes and how they work, but when I try to do this I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError for class A.

Could not initialize class A

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class A

Is this behavior expected when making a call to another static method from a inner static class?

Comment: Not. It is a classpath issue or a missing compiled class.

Comment: [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34413)

Comment: From what I've read, this error can also be caused by static initialization exceptions though. The reason I'm not sure it's a missing compiled class or classpath issue is because all other places where this missing class (in my example, class A) is used does not raise any issues.

Comment: It is indeed possible but to think of it as a possibility you should provide the real code. `NoClassDefFoundError` is an exception not a compilation error. And your code has no executable class, that is, a class with a `main(String args[])` method.

Comment: Hmmm. Good to know that that's not the issue at least, thanks! In the real code, the problem originates from a junit test being run which through a series of calls eventually gets to the static method call resulting in this error. The reason I did not post the real code is because it would be a lot of code to paste, and I just wanted to validate that the issue isn't due to inner static classes (which I'm not very familiar with)